# How to add CheckBox on QTreeView + QFileSystemModel

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, treeview

I want to select some different folders in the treeview. There are two solution in QT like this:
[image]

1. QTreeView + QFileSystemModel, But how add the treebox in it? I dotn't know at all. In the same time, QFileSystemModel is asychronised, so after you choose a folder, then expand the directory, you will find the sub-folder were not choosen. How can I solve the this problem?
2. QTreeView + QDirModel, there is a good model and it work well:
   http://www.programmershare.com/2041913/
   But QDirModel is synchronised. So we have to wait a long time when choose a big folder. We can accept a long time, but how I can know the selection is finished?

Thanks anyway.

Comment: what do you mean under "how I can know the selection is finished"? you should place somewhere "OK" button and after click to collect checked items

Comment: When you choose a big folder by QDirModel, it will cost you 5 minute or more. Because it will select all its sub-folder and all sub-files. So when all the selections are finished, the programme should know it and so we can restore the cursor/show some messages to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your example](http://www.programmershare.com/2041913/) should be tweaked a bit to use `QFileSystemModel`.

The trick is to declare the `checkedIndexes` set as `mutable` and update it inside the `CFileSystemModel::data` method.

```
QVariant CFileSystemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::CheckStateRole)
    {
        if (checkedIndexes.contains(index))
        {
            return checkedIndexes.contains(index) ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked;
        }
        else
        {
            int checked = Qt::Unchecked;

            QModelIndex parent = index.parent();
            while (parent.isValid())
            {
                if (checkedIndexes.contains(parent))
                {
                    checked = Qt::Checked;
                    break;
                }

                parent = parent.parent();
            }

            if (checked == Qt::Checked)
            {
                checkedIndexes.insert(parent);
            }

            return checked;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return QFileSystemModel::data(index, role);
    }
}
```

When you open a directory node in a view, `QFileSystemModel` starts to load new contents. After they are loaded, the view retieves new data using `CFileSystemModel::data` function, which checks if new nodes anchestors were checked and returns proper `Qt::CheckStateRole` value (and also updates the `checkedIndexes` set).

Comment: If anyone comes across this piece of code, note that it has at least one flaw: the current item should be inserted, and not the parent - `checkedIndexes.insert(index)`